# netbeans project collapses tree menu

Tags: java, netbeans

NetBeans project collapses tree menu, but this did not occur earlier.

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.4 (Build 201310111528)
NetBeans IDE  NetBeans 7.4 Patch 2
Java: 1.7.0_45; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.45-b08
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_45-b18
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1251; ru_RU (nb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually for that kind of issues there is no solution. Try to report the bug to the netbeans community if it is not already reported. If you want to have a clear solution to your problem change you netbeans to an earliest version or reinstall this particular version.

PS: You should update you Java version to the latest one (1.7.0_51).

Answer (score 0):

there may be some issues with the istallation processes try 
1) reinstaiing
2) changing perspective mode 
3) refeshing project

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with your Netbeans compatibility, because you are using 64 bit system. Your Netbeans is might be compatible with 32 bit system only. Or other possible thing is that Netbeans is not installed properly.

So to solve this problem you can do this:

1. Reinstall Netbeans
2. Search for 64 bit compatible Netbeans version, Download it, and then install it properly.
3. Delete your existing project and create a new project.